# 4s backup from 3gs

Tags: iphone, backup

can I please ask, if it's alright if I do the backup from 3gs to iphone 4s? I mean, does it affect something on the iphone 4s? I read somewhere that the users who did this backup had a problems with iphone (they don't have a siri there for example and the iphone 4s worked after backup just as their old 3gs without the new 4s tricks etc.)

Thank you very very much for any answer. I'll be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backups are compatible with later model devices (but not the other way around - ie, you can't restore a 4S onto a 3GS usually). You can safely restore a backup made of an iPhone 3GS onto an iPhone 4S without problem.

I (and several people I know) have done this multiple times without problem. For example, my current iPhone 5 has data on it that was originally on a 3GS, which was restored onto a 4S and then onto the 5. Siri worked fine on the 4S and works fine on the 5 (along with everything else).